# LINQ Select()/Any() misbehaving?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
return lStoredRecords.Select(u => 
                                 u.sCardId == sCardId && 
                                 u.rtMode == eRecordType &&
                                 u.dtTime >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15.0)).Any();
```

But for some reason it always returns `True`,

`lStoredRecords` contains one record such that it's `dtTime` **doesn't** satisfy the above condition - so I was expecting the above line of code to return `False`

Any ideas?

Comment: You're selecting a boolean value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, it's not clear why you're using `Select` at all. I'd expect you to just use `Any` on its own, specifying the predicate as an argument.

Secondly, if `lStoredRecords` has any records at all, this will *always* return `true` - [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) without a predicate just returns whether there are any records in the input sequence, and `Select` is just going to project an input value to an ouptut value - it's not doing any filtering at all. If you were expecting to filter, you should have been using [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803).

Thirdly, it's not clear that you want `Any` in the first place. From your question:

> `lStoredRecords` contains one record such that it's `dtTime` doesn't satisfy the above condition - so I was expecting the above line of code to return `False`

If you want it to return `false` if any of the records fails to satisfy a condition, you should almost certainly be using `All` instead - you want to check whether *all* the input values match your condition.

So basically you want:

```
return lStoredRecords.All(u => u.sCardId == sCardId && 
                               u.rtMode == eRecordType &&
                               u.dtTime >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15.0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code projects `lStoredRecords` to a list of `bool`s. Since this list does have elements (perhaps some `true` and some `false` - that doesn't matter), `Any()` returns true.

Use instead:

```
return lStoredRecords.Any(u => 
                          u.sCardId == sCardId && 
                          u.rtMode == eRecordType &&
                          u.dtTime >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do this...

```
return lStoredRecords.Any(u => 
                             u.sCardId == sCardId && 
                             u.rtMode == eRecordType &&
                             u.dtTime >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15.0));
```

Read up on what `Select` and `Any` do (`Where` is also relevant here).

The `Select` expression you wrote will transform `lStoredRecords` to an `IEnumerable<bool>`, then check if this has any elements. It will be filled with `true` or `false` according to your `Select` expression. I think you expect `Select` to be doing what `Where` actually does. But still the better choice is to put the expression in `Any`. This will prevent unnecessary operations.